# What kind of a sorting algorithm is this?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, computer-science

This is an example of a c program to sort a list of names... I'm new to algorithms that's why I need to know what type it is!
What are real life examples could I use it for too?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 int main() {
 char *str[5], *temp;
 int i, j, n;

 printf("\nHow many names do you want to have?");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 printf("\nEnter the name %d: ", i);
 flushall();
 gets(str[i]);
 }

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
     if (strcmp(str[j], str[j + 1]) > 0) {
        strcpy(temp, str[j]);
        strcpy(str[j], str[j + 1]);
        strcpy(str[j + 1], temp);
     }
  }
}

flushall();

printf("\nSorted List : ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  puts(str[i]);

return (0);
}
```

Comment: What did you think it was when you wrote it?

Comment: Did you, in fact, try to run it? It should explode in horrible ways because no memory is ever allocated for the strings.

Comment: Looks like *Bubble Sort* to me.

Comment: That code has undefined behavior, `temp` is never initialized to be a valid pointer before being used as the destination in a `strcpy()` call. Scary. The memory "management" for `str[]` is equally missing, and it uses `gets()`. Yikes.

Comment: Actually I didn't.. It's that I'm learning from c4learn.com that has the examples!

Comment: @AhmedSamir Well, then the quality of that particular resource can be considered way below reasonable. Stop using it, since it'll just teach you cr*p you're going to have to unlearn later.

Comment: As mentioned, it's a bubble sort, As for real life examples, it's fine for a relatively small number of elements. Somewhere between 1,000 and 10,000 or more elements, you'll want to use a faster sort algorithm, like heap sort, merge sort, quick sort, ... . Other's here have already pointer out that the rest of the code needs to be fixed (no allocation of memory for the strings, ... )

Answer (score 3):

I hope its a bubble sorting. And with this you can arrange numbers in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Yes, but an inefficient one. He could have replaced `for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)` by `for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)`. It would be slightly more efficient. We must hope that `n` is never bigger than 5.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the program is invalid. It does not allocate memory where it is going to store strings. As result it is a very risky step to ask the user 
how many names does he want to have because there is no space to store strings in the program.:)

You could use a two-dimensional variable length character array for the strings and standard function `fgets` instead of `gets` to enter the strings.

As for the sort algorithm then it is a bad realization of the bubble sort.:)